# Can multiple subnets reach each other connecting to a central IPsec VPN?

Tags: vpn, ipsec

Say you have three networks, networks A, B, and C.

-A is an ipsec VPN server

-B is connected to A through ipsec

-C is connected to A through ipsec

Can network B access network C?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the traffic selectors negotiated via IKEv2 and the resulting IPsec policies.

For B to access network C it has to propose that subnet (or multiple if necessary) as remote traffic selector, A will negotiate it as its local traffic selector for this connection.  The same goes for C, which needs access to subnet B.

Or they could both propose e.g. 0.0.0.0/0 as remote traffic selector, which A could then narrow to all the necessary subnets behind other clients via its local traffic selector.